# Different way to communicate two Unity android Application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, networking

We are working on a project in which we need to established communication between two Unity android application. right now we are using socket programing over wifi for the same. Everything was working fine, until we are working with less data. When we need to work on real data, we found that our Wifi router got hanged some time. We need to on/off mobile wifi to start communication again.

So we are looking for other options, through which we can communicate two device and share data instantly.

Comment: BLE is the other one but it requires the two devices to be within range. I would think any other technology is just based on one or the other. I could be wrong.